# Can I edit hosts without sudo?

Tags: permissions

Currently when I want to edit my hosts file, I need to use `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, is there anything I can do to say "allow the `tom` user to edit the hosts file without needing sudo"?

Comment: Reboot and use the grub prompt to get root permissions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can, but it's a bad idea. The whole point of the permissions system is preventing non-privileged users and attackers from doing stuff like writing to system files, running hostile code, and so on. By far the best thing to do is just keep on using `sudo` when you need to edit system files. That's best practice and it's the reason we have `sudo`

I don't recommend either of the following methods, but they are safer than the dreaded `chmod 777`. You *could*, for example, change the group ownership of `/etc/hosts` and give the group write permission:

```
sudo addgroup editors            #make a new group
sudo adduser $USER editors       #add yourself to it
sudo chown :editors /etc/hosts   #change the group ownership
sudo chmod 664 /etc/hosts        #give the group write permission
```

You would now be able to edit the file without `sudo`. Or, you could use ACLs, if you have the `acl` package (installed for sure in 15.04 and later)

```
sudo setfacl -m $USER:rw /etc/hosts
```

But, again, I don't recommend either of those actions. Just use `sudo`.

Comment: I think it's important to note that you can add "tom ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nano /etc/hosts" to your sudoers file. You'd still need to use sudo but you won't need your password.

Comment: @LeoIzen see [Will's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/895649/527764) for a solution based on that. I don't want to encroach on other answers. Also, the question asks how can I edit without `sudo`, not how to edit without a password.

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't adjust the permissions of any system related file

What you can do is make a basic script

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Call it whatever you want, for example, edithosts.sh and put it in a scripts folder inside your home folder.

`chmod 700 /path/to/script/file/edithosts.sh`  This will prevent unauthorised reading or writing to the file because ss TripeHound said, the contents of this file are now run with root permissions with no password.

Then add the following line to `/etc/sudoers`

```
tom ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script/file/edithosts.sh
```

That will allow you to `sudo sh /path/to/script/file/edithosts.sh` without having to enter a password

Recommended solution

As @paul pointed out in the comments, `sudoedit` could be a better solution.

```
tom ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit /etc/hosts
```

Because this solely allows editing of `/etc/hosts` and doesn't leave you running an elevated text editor

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55893/discussion-on-answer-by-will-can-i-edit-hosts-without-sudo).