# What is the purpose of the line 127.0.1.1 <HOSTNAME> in the file /etc/hosts in Ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, localhost, hostname

This question is linked to [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477503/when-change-the-hostname-the-content-of-the-file-etc-hosts-must-be-updated-manu) which explains that to change the hostname of a system with lubuntu 22.04 installed I have to modify 2 files:

- `/etc/hostname` (by the command `nmcli`)
- `/etc/hosts`

While I'm thinking that I have understood the scope of the file `/etc/hostname`, I don't know what is the scope of the presence of the line `127.0.1.1 <HOSTNAME>` in the file `/etc/hosts`.

The question is:
What is the purpose of the line 127.0.1.1  in the file `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: It's basically so that your hostname resolved to *something*, which may not always be the case if this entry is absent and DNS resolution is attempted. `sudo` is one tool famous for errors about problems with resolving the local system's hostname.

Comment: Thank you. In other Linux system I usually think that the hostname is connected to 127.0.0.1 and I have not noted that existence of a configuration which links the hostname to 127.0.1.1. May be I wasn't paying attention!

Comment: In most `/etc/hosts` files I have seen, usually `127.0.0.1` is set to `localhost`, and some other loopback address (in this case `127.0.1.1`, but I have seen others) is used for the hostname